# I want to prove the proposition that the absolute value of integral expression must be monotonically decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, legendre-polynomials

For arbitrary $r_0$ and $P_l(\text{cos}(\theta))$ be the Legendre polynomials,

$$
E_n=\int_{r0}^\infty \int_0^\pi  -\text{sin}^3(\theta)(\left(
\left(\text{cot}(\theta) \sum_{l=0}^n R_l(r) \partial_\theta P_l(\text{cos}(\theta))\right) + r \left(\sum_{l=0}^n R'_l(r) P_l(\text{cos}(\theta))\right)\right)^2\text{d}r\text{d}\theta
$$

(monotonically) decreases as $n$ increases. i.e. I want to prove that the sequence $|E_n|$ must be decreasing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.